# Laravel - redirect to route with data after register

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

I want to redirect to 'email/verify' with some data(newly created user) within it after registration using Laravel Auth.

Is there any way to customize the redirection after registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do more than just redirect to a route you can override the `registered` method on your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` (which comes from the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` trait):

```
/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    // do what you would like and return the response you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
protected $redirectTo = '/your_url';
```

After that you have to use like this

```
protected function registered(Request $request){
    // After successful register you have to use like this
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```